# Why LocalForward in .ssh/config returns error while ssh -L works as expected

Tags: ssh

I add LocalForward in the `.ssh/config` file for connecting to the MongoDB on a Ubuntu 14 server.

```
LocalForward 27017 loccalhost:27017
```

When I connect to the MongoDB, there is an error message:

```
channel 9: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

However, it works when I use `ssh -L` in bash

```
ssh -L 27017:localhost:27017
```

Is there any difference between these two methods? Can I make it work with the `.ssh/config` file?

Comment: `LocalForward 27017 loccalhost:27017` is it relevant that you misspelled "localhost" here?

Comment: oh, yes. Kenster, you are right. Now it works. Thank you.